# pagination with nodejs mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs mongodb.
Here is my code:

```
var deferred = defer();
    User.find({
            _id: id

    }).then(data => {
        User.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: [data[0].loc[0], data[0].loc[1]],
                    spherical: true,
                    distanceField: "dis",
                    maxDistance : 1000/6378137,
                    distanceMultiplier: 6378137
                }
            },{ "$sort": { "dis": 1}}
        ]).then(count => {
            User.aggregate([
                {
                    $geoNear: {
                        near: [data[0].loc[0], data[0].loc[1]],
                        spherical: true,
                        distanceField: "dis",
                        maxDistance : 1000/6378137,
                        distanceMultiplier: 6378137
                    }
                },{ "$sort": { "dis": 1}},
                {$limit : 1},
                {$skip : 1}
            ]).then(result => {
                deferred.resolve({
                    count: count.length/2,
                    result: result
                })
            }, err=> {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }, err=> {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
```

The problem is when skip and limit are equal I get empty query. As I understand limit shows number per page. What is problem here?

Comment: Have you take a look at [`express-paginate`](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate) and [`mongoose-paginate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate)?

Comment: No, I would like to do it wthout any external library